# Is there a way to calculate the half range Fourier series in SymPy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

For example, if I want the Fourier series of the function *f(x) = x(π-x)* on [0, π], I can calculate the coefficients of the sine series:

[image]

which works by considering *f(x)* in a [half range Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_range_Fourier_series), the half interval [0, π] extended to [-π, 0] by taking the extension of *f(x)* to be an odd function (so I don't need the cosine terms in the full Fourier series expansion).

Using SymPy, however, I get a cosine series:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x', real=True)
f = x * (sp.pi - x)
s = sp.fourier_series(f, (x, 0, sp.pi))
s.truncate(4)

-cos(2*x) - cos(4*x)/4 - cos(6*x)/9 + pi**2/6
```

Even constructing a `Piecewise` function with the correct parity doesn't work:

```
p = sp.Piecewise((-f, x < 0), (f, x >= 0))
ps = sp.fourier_series(p, (x, 0, sp.pi))
ps.truncate(4)

-cos(2*x) - cos(4*x)/4 - cos(6*x)/9 + pi**2/6
```

The cosine series sort-of approximates *f(x)* but not nearly as well as the sine one. Is there any way to force SymPy to do what I did with paper and pen?

Comment: Looking at the source code of Sympy 1.11, the sine series approximation is only called if 0 is the center of the limits, and the function is odd. For now, I think you have to do it manually (with SymPy). Maybe you can also open an issue for a feature request...

Comment: @Stef I converted the image from .gif to .png.  It should work better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating directly as proposed in the first answer by @Oscar is a simple solution.

It is interesting anyway to understand why your approach is not working.

1. To get an odd function, for negative `x` values, we need to use
   `fneg = x * (sp.pi + x)` (`= -f(-x)`)
2. Then, to calculate the coefficients, you need to integrate from -PI to PI.

**Code**

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x', real=True)
f = x * (sp.pi - x)
fneg = x * (sp.pi + x)
p = sp.Piecewise((fneg, x < 0), (f, x >= 0))
ps = sp.fourier_series(p, (x, -sp.pi, sp.pi))
print ('ps = ', ps.truncate(4))
```

**Result:**

```
ps =  8*sin(x)/pi + 8*sin(3*x)/(27*pi) + 8*sin(5*x)/(125*pi) + 8*sin(7*x)/(343*pi)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was missing and I'm sure the Piecewise approach would work in general as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the series coefficients directly:

```
In [52]: f
Out[52]: x⋅(π - x)

In [53]: n = symbols('n', integer=True)

In [54]: bn = 2/pi*integrate(f*sin(n*x), (x, 0, pi))

In [55]: bn
Out[55]: 
  ⎛⎧        n                ⎞
  ⎜⎪  2⋅(-1)    2            ⎟
  ⎜⎪- ─────── + ──  for n ≠ 0⎟
2⋅⎜⎨      3      3           ⎟
  ⎜⎪     n      n            ⎟
  ⎜⎪                         ⎟
  ⎝⎩      0         otherwise⎠
──────────────────────────────
              π               

In [56]: f_approx = summation(bn*sin(n*x), (n, 0, 5))

In [57]: f_approx
Out[57]: 
8⋅sin(x)   8⋅sin(3⋅x)   8⋅sin(5⋅x)
──────── + ────────── + ──────────
   π          27⋅π        125⋅π   

In [58]: plot(f_approx, f, (x, -pi, 2*pi))
```

[image: half sin plot]